# Jet performance chips & mfgr warranties

Tags: performance

I was toying with the idea of getting a bit extra from my 2011 Chevy Cruze Eco. It's a great car but I think the turbo is being control via the computer and in my opinion, could be a bit better. I was looking at the jet performance stage 1 chips. Would using a chip like this void the mfgr warranty I have with GM? If not, is it worth the money?

http://www.summitracing.com/parts/JET-11009/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm generally suspicious of get rich quick schemes.  I've been holding off on chip-like improvements to my car until I'm really convinced that the software is all there and it's a 2004 model.

On the other hand, remember that even a small turbo motor will benefit from attention to the intake and exhaust components.  Remember that the engine is an air pump: if you can improve its ability to pump that air, it will reward you.

Admittedly, changes to intakes and exhausts generally cost more money that popping in a new chip.  That said, I'm a sincere advocate that wrenching is more fun than popping in the latest chip.  Besides, a better intake and exhaust path will almost certainly mean that the better ECU program (when you get it) will have a more efficient overall system to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Modifications almost always affect the warranty.  The warranty is based upon a standard car used in typical circumstances.  If you go outside of those (either by modifying things or using the car atypically (like racing it)) then the warranty is in jeopardy.  It comes down to how generous the dealer/company happen to be the day that you need work...

That said, chip replacements in general are relatively low risk compared to other modifications, but it does carry risk depending on how aggressive the individual chip is.

Comment: thats what i figured but I know there are some parts like a few cold air intake kits that claim they won't void the warranty. I think with the way things have been for auto companies, they probably wont be so forgiving. Best if I have them do it or leave it as is.

Comment: You might want to edit that last sentence: sight unseen, it's hard to say a priori whether a particular chip is low risk.  It's certainly low *effort* but a bad program could result in a blown gasket if it happened to have an excessively lean mixture at higher boost levels.

Comment: Modified to more appropriately reflect the meaning I intended to convey.  :-)

Comment: My thoughts are much more in line with your new edit.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a law that says they have to prove your modification is what actually broke the component for them to void the warranty? Just installing a chip won't shouldn't void anything. Call Jet and talk to them, they should know.

Comment: Certainly not in the UK - here if you haven't told the insurance company the exact detail of all the mods you have made (including chipping) your insurance becomes null and void. They won't tell you this until you try to claim, obviously.